# R plot linear regression and standard deviation using abline

Tags: r, plot

I can plot a linear regression line using abline:

```
x= runif(10)
y=runif(10)
fit1 <- lm(x ~ y )
sd2 <- sd(abs(fit1$residuals))*2

plot(x,y)
abline(fit1)
```

But how can I plot the standard deviation  lines using abline.
I tried:

```
abline(fit1+sd2)
abline(fit1-sd2)
```

but I get an error.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: The confidence interval for a linear regression isn't constant. What you are proposing here isn't really valid statistically. If you want to better understand how to create confidence intervals or prediction intervals from linear models, you should be asking your question over at [stats.se] where questions about statistics are on-topic.

Comment: See `?predict`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`abline(fit)` works because it takes in intercept and slope from `fit` to draw the line, it is identical to my second line of code. So abline with `sd2` can work if we move the line upp `sd2` units and down `sd2` units. You can achieve it by my third and fourth lines.
 `plot(x,y)
 abline(fit1$coefficients[1],fit1$coefficients[2])
 abline(fit1$coefficients[1]+sd2,fit1$coefficients[2])
 abline(fit1$coefficients[1]-sd2,fit1$coefficients[2])`

Hope this explanation of `abline` is helpful.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ggplot` to achieve this:

```
x= runif(10)
y=runif(10)
fit1 <- lm(x ~ y )
sd2 <- sd(fit1$residuals)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame(x,y), aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
geom_point() + 
geom_smooth(method="lm")
```